# by foreach loop how to get value in one variable in echo in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, sql

There are guest_name and guest_number and two variables that are fetching the record from database in while loop..

```
     while( $row = $result-> fetch_assoc() )
     {
         $name = $row['getaway_name']." <br>";
         $start = $row['check_in_date']." <br>";
         $end = $row['check_out_date']." <br>";
         $guest_n[]= $row['guest_name'];
         $guest_number[]= $row['guest_phone'];

         //$cp = array();
         $arr1 = range(strtotime($row['check_in_date']),strtotime($row['check_out_date']), "86400");
         //$arr2 = range(strtotime($row['check_out_date']),strtotime($row['check_in_date']), "86400");

         array_walk_recursive($arr1, function(&$element) { $element = date("j-n-Y", $element); });
         //array_walk_recursive($arr2, function(&$element) { $element = date("d-n-Y", $element); });
         foreach ($arr1  as $value)
         {
             $arr2[]= $value;
         }
         $arrt= (array_merge($guest_n, $guest_number));
         print_r($arrt);
         foreach($arrt as $val)
         {
             $arr_t= $val;
             echo 'foreach' .$arr_t;
         }
```

I want to show user name and phone number on calendar by fetching from database like one user has a room booked from 21-23 and second user has room booked from 26-29, so I want to show user info on dates, in my case same info is coming on all the dates..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// Add New Dates and Block Out Booked Days Below 
/*var unavailableDates1 = ["20-5-2016", "21-5-2016", "22-5-2016", "23-5-2016", "5-6-2016", "7-6-2016", "8-6-2016",
                      "15-6-2016", "16-6-2016", "25-6-2016", "26-6-2016", "27-6-2016", "28-6-2016", "14-2-2016",
                      "15-7-2016", "16-7-2016", "17-7-2016", "18-7-2016", "19-7-2016","20-7-2016","21-7-2016",
                      ];   */
var unavailableDates = <?php echo json_encode($arr2); ?>;
var unavailab = <?php echo json_encode($arr_t); ?>;

document.write(unavailab);
document.write(unavailableDates);

function unavailable(date) {

    dmy = date.getDate() + "-" + (date.getMonth() + 1 ) + "-" + date.getFullYear();

    if($.inArray(dmy, unavailableDates) == -1) {

        return [true, ""];

    }else {
    /// -> from this line i want to show the data that are coming from user
        return [false, "",unavailab];
    }
}
$(function() {
    $("#Datepicker1").datepicker({
        numberOfMonths:3,
        beforeShowDay: unavailable
    }); 
});


</script>

Please help
```